# SQL SERVER - Dynamic SQL insert statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a .txt file which is like screenshot attached

I need to parse the notepad and get the [cust] count and amount for different category of a,b & c and store into one table.

Here the challenge is a,b,c is not a permanent number of entity. It may add up that is a,b,c,d,e and its count & amount will come.

or decrease into a & b and its count and amount will come in some case.

How to parse the values. Any idea?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: First of all, did you try anything? Second, I don't see how is the question connected to SQL-Server, unless that text is copied from a query result inside SSMS. Plus, I would give more data since you said that the number of entity is dynamic.

Comment: You cant import provided  data into in to sql server with the above format.It should be like comma separated ,Tab separated so the you that you can import data in to sql

Comment: SSIS is not going to be a good fit for this type of data. It's easy to skip the first N rows so the first "data" row would be cust 1/33/123 etc. However, that trailing line with the ---- will result in SSIS throwing an error because it doesn't conform to the previous row's layout for data

Comment: @PaulKaram. I tried following, using ssis and dump the data into one physical table in single column and used substring to parse.

Comment: @Sreenu131 But the input file is like attached only :-(

Comment: @billinkc Do you have any suggestion what would be the best fit

Comment: SSIS (source, transformation) indeed is not a good option for non structured data processing. You have to write down a custom code to fetch the data then build up a dynamic insert/update statement.

Comment: In your question you say that you might have more than three "cnt,amt" column pairs, then in your comment you say that the input file is "like attached only" - those are inconsistent statements.

Comment: However, that input file is nicely human-readable, but it's not nice for computers.  What is the source of your input?  Can you get it changed to be "tall" rather than "wide"?

Comment: @Brian There is a gap in understanding. sreenu131 asked for comma or tab delimited file. So i mentioned that file format will be like attached. Also i don't have control over input file.

Comment: In that case, you've got a problem.  Most automated data import tools - all the ones that I'm familiar with, at least - require the input to be in a fixed format.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file with a script task and generate the desired input statements to execute.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or how this can be done inside script task